# The wrong links in gnubin but still work

Tags: symlink

I check the directory `ls -l /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` and come with

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 12 Oct 27 12:50 '[' -> '../../bin/g['
lrwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 16 Oct 27 12:50  b2sum -> ../../bin/gb2sum
lrwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 17 Oct 27 12:50  base32 -> ../../bin/gbase32
lrwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 17 Oct 27 12:50  base64 -> ../../bin/gbase64
lrwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 19 Oct 27 12:50  basename -> ../../bin/gbasename
lrwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 14 Oct 27 12:50  cat -> ../../bin/gcat
....
```

Pore through it carefully

```
`rwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 16 Oct 27 12:50  b2sum -> ../../bin/gb2sum`
```

it indicate that `b2sum` links to it grandparent folder,

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin
$ cd ../..
$ pwd
/usr/local/opt/coreutils
$ ls | grep gb2sum
# return nothing
```

Actually, there does not exist such a function `gb2sum`,it resides in

```
$ which gb2sum
/usr/local/bin/gb2sum
```

The address has not relation with `../../bin/gb2sum`, 
why the link is demonstrated as`lrwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 16 Oct 27 12:50  b2sum -> ../../bin/gb2sum`?

Comment: The links point to `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin`, not `/usr/local/opt/coreutils`; doesn’t `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin/gb2sum` exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you've overlooked one component of the symlinked path:

```
rwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 16 Oct 27 12:50  b2sum -> ../../bin/gb2sum
                                                     ^----------here
```

You've proceeded up through the `../..` parts but didn't do either of:

```
ls -l bin/gb2sum
```

or

```
cd bin
ls -l gb2sum
```

It's likely the case that `/usr/local/bin/gb2sum` is itself a symlink that results in `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin/gb2sum`.